# Flutter Firestore Geo query for certain distance from my location

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, geolocation

I stores my users data include their live location as **GeoPoint** data type in my firebase database.
Now I need to select and get users from database with certain distance from my position.
I use this line of code for retrieving my location:

```
position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

No I need a firebase query in flutter to retrieve users which have 500 meters around me.It means I should retrieve all users with distance of 500 meters from firebase database.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found solution:

```
position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
await getGenderIcons(context);
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;
double lat = 0.0144927536231884;
double lon = 0.0181818181818182;
double distance = 1000*0.000621371;
double lowerLat = position.latitude - (lat * distance);
double lowerLon = position.longitude - (lon * distance);
double greaterLat = position.latitude + (lat * distance);
double greaterLon = position.longitude + (lon * distance);
GeoPoint lesserGeopoint = GeoPoint(lowerLat,lowerLon);
GeoPoint greaterGeopoint = GeoPoint(greaterLat,greaterLon);
querySnapshot = await usersRef
    .where("livelocation", isGreaterThan: lesserGeopoint)
    .where("livelocation", isLessThan: greaterGeopoint)
    .limit(100)
    .get();
```

Comment: Is working perfectly fine?

Comment: Can you explain more why you initiate all those calculations?

Comment: It works perfectly. For thous who wants to use a little explaination:
double lat = 0.0144927536231884; //this shoudnt be changed
double lon = 0.0181818181818182; //this shoudnt be changed
double distance = 1000*0.000621371; //changue the 1000 (1km) for the value you need. This is the only change you need to do

Thanks a lot